# Java local variable Thread Safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm new to multithreading and i'm confused if this method is thread safe or not as i'm not doing a new on HttpURLConnection conn......................................

```
      protected byte[] someMethod(Authenticator authenticator, String url, boolean doPost) throws Exception {
    try {
      URL aUrl = new URL(url);
      strBldr = new StringBuilder();
      AuthenticatedURL.Token token = new AuthenticatedURL.Token();
      TestConnectionConfigurator connConf = new TestConnectionConfigurator();
      AuthenticatedURL authUrl = new AuthenticatedURL(authenticator, connConf);
      HttpURLConnection conn = authUrl.openConnection(aUrl, token);
      if (!connConf.invoked)
          throw new IOException("failed to invoked");
      String tokenStr = token.toString();
      if (doPost) {
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
      }
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.connect();

      if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

          BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                            conn.getInputStream());

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArraySt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               int counter;
               while ((counter = in.read()) != -1) {
                   byteArraySt.write(counter);
               }
               byte [] bArray = new byte[byteArraySt.toByteArray().length];
               bArray = byteArraySt.toByteArray();


            in.close();
            return bArray;
        }
```

Comment: More on thread safety: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076747/core-java/design-for-thread-safety.html

Comment: If all the variables are local and stay that way, the question of thread-safety cannot possibly arise. Why are you setting `doOutput` to true and then doing no output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule to write thread-safe code, you have to focus on mutable shared state. Local variables are not shared and so they are not a concern.

Your code should be thread-safe but you should check if the `authenticator` object that is passed to the method (and thus could be shared by different threads) is actually thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm passing "new Authenticator" from another method. and it's not declared as an instance variable

Comment: another question I have is, isn't "conn" a shared object?

Comment: @private5181 It is a method-local variable.

Comment: `conn` is not a shared object because it is created within the method and it doesn't escape from it.